# serverless webpack doesn't bundle handlers.js

Tags: webpack, serverless

I am new to webpack and serverless, so please forgive me if this seems trivial. I copied these codes from [npm serverless-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-webpack).

I tried to use `serverless webpack --out dist`, but my command line didn't recognise `webpack`. If I tried to `serverless deploy <opts> <opt>`, then it compiled and bundled into a .serverless but missing the essential JS files.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: ["babel-loader"],
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**Serverless.yml**

```
service: hello-world
frameworkVersion: '>=1.2.0 <2.0.0'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  deploymentBucket:
     name: test-bucket
plugin:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-prune-plugin
custom:
  prune:
    automatic: true
    number: 3
  webpack: webpack.config.js
  webpackIncludeModules:
    packagePath: ./src/package.json
    forceInclude:
       - express
       - body-parser
functions:
  getHelloWorld:
    handler: functions/test.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: test/hello
          method: get
```

**webpack:** 4.22.0 (global)

**serverless-webpack:**  5.3.0 (global)

Comment: Looks like your `serverless.yml` is misconfigured and/or out-of-sync with respect to your `webpack.config.js`. Can you post that as well?

Comment: @dashmug i added the `serverless.yml`

Comment: try placing plug-ins in yml at the top

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. First, install webpack.

   ```
   npm install --save-dev webpack
   ```
2. Install plugin serverless webpack

   ```
   npm install serverless-webpack --save-dev
   ```
3. Add plugin to serverless.yml

   ```
   service: hello-world
   plugins:
       - serverless-webpack
   custom:
       webpackIncludeModules: true
   ```
4. Your package.json will be something that:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "test-process": "mocha --require babel-core/register ./tests/unit.test.js",
       "deploy": "./node_modules/.bin/serverless remove --stage dev --region us-east-1 && ./node_modules/.bin/serverless deploy -v --stage dev --region us-east-1"
   }
   ```
5. Then, you can deploy with this command: **npm run deploy**
6. Also, with [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) you can test your code before doing the deploy. For that, you will have that configure [babel](https://babeljs.io/)

**I prepare you a basic example hello-world with webpack4 and serverless:**

```
https://github.com/ns4lin4s/stackoverflow
```

**Don't forget, add response application/json in apigateway:**

[image]

let me know how did work..

Comment: cheers @ene_salinas for getting back to me. The main reason for it didn't work was yml didn't know I wanted to use these plugins, because I wrote "plugin" and not "plugins".

Comment: @MayField haha ok, then is it answer resolved your issue?

Comment: Yes in a way you did answer my question, by listing all the necessary steps to bundle the files.